# Aptana won't save editor preferences

Tags: ide, aptana

I've got a little (big) problem in Aptana. Whenever I try to edit my settings for a specific editor, I click "Apply", then "OK", but my preferences don't get saved, and if I open the settings again, the default ones are shown. What might be causing the problem?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with Aptana build 3.0.4.201108101506.

I'm looking forward to reading your suggestions.

Alessandro Desantis

EDIT: The situations changed with version 3.0.5. Now, YAML editor's preferences get erased when closing the settings window as before, while others editors' ones are overridden with defaults when closing the IDE... This is very strange.

Comment: Does this happen for all editors, or just specific ones? Is it a particular setting you are changing?

Comment: It happens for all editors. I'm trying to set tab policy to 4 spaces, but it gets set to 2 (or the default value) once I click 'Apply' and 'OK'.

Comment: Things got a little better in the latest release. It now saves settings for all editors except for YAML. It keeps being set to 2 spaces when I want it to be 4. I really don't understand why.

Comment: That might well be a bug. Could you please file a ticket?

Comment: Here it is: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3621

Comment: happens to me as well. won't save color preferences (for changed files). Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.7.201112281312 on Win XP

Comment: Seems like the issue has been closed because they couldn't replicate it...

Comment: happening to myself also - specifically the *.less and *.sass file types.  always defaulting back to tab spacing as 2 - driving me nuts.  on mac osx here - sometimes my settings will update but on application restart they have reverted to normal

Comment: Have any of you checked the workspace permissions? What happens if you open Aptanas as root?

Answer (score 0):

1. open preferences (settings)
2. click General
3. click editors
4. click text editors
5. change displayed tab width to 4
6. check insert spaces for tabs
7. click apply
8. click ok
9. open preferences (settings)
10. click aptana studio
11. click editors
12. click YAML (or desired editor)
13. change tab policy to use spaces
14. change tab size to 4

this worked for me